# trying to toggle the color of some p tags using getElementsByName

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

This is what I have but I do not know how to target the different id for orange

```
function toggleColor(){
    document.getElementsByName("color").style.color = 'blue';
    document.getElementById().style.color = 'orange';
}


<ul>
    <li><p id="skg"name="color" onclick="toggleColor();">SKG</p></li>
    <li><p id="tech" name="color" onclick="toggleColor();">Tech</p></li>
    <li><p id="upd" name="color" onclick="toggleColor();">UPD</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What you actually want? What should happen when user clicks on item?

Comment: document.getElementById("tech").style.color = 'orange'; ??

Comment: I want actve/clicked element to be orange and other elements color to stay or change to blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a really a bad practice attach the javascript events in the HTML so I recommend use the `addEventListener` function to do this. You will get the same result but with a clean HTML and a code easy to reuse and maintain.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><p name="colors" id="skg">SKG</p></li>
    <li><p name="colors" id="tech">Tech</p></li>
    <li><p name="colors" id="upd">UPD</p></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var colors = document.getElementsByName('colors');
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i ++ ){
  colors[i].addEventListener('click', toggleColor);
}

function toggleColor(){
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i ++ ){
    colors[i].style.color = 'blue';
  }
  this.style.color = 'orange';
}
```

**CSS**

```
p { 
 color: blue;
}
```

Check out [this](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/OPLzwX) codepen.

Comment: I am sorry I do not know if I explained it correctly.Your way only changes the color of the element that is is clicked, I actually want when the element is clicked to toggle its color and change the other elements color back. elemet1, elemnt2 element3 color is blue... click element1 and its color is changed to orange...click element2 its color is changed to orange and element1 and element3 are changed to blue..... meaning active element color is orange on click and other elements remain or are changed to blue..... your version just changes the clicked elements color

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check out if it is what you want.

Comment: yes you genius you...... can you also put up the code you had up first as well so I can compare the 2 to study them?

Comment: Look at the codepen. I just only changed the toogleColor function so I added the old function to the codepen with the name toggleColorOld. You can compare there. There better solutions to implement but as you are new in JS I think that this is the easiest to understand. When you are ready let me know and I can show you a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer jQuery but if you want to do it without, you could do somthing like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zjv1euqx/

```
<script>
    function toggleColor(e){
        if(e.style.color == 'blue'){
             e.style.color = 'orange';
        }else{
             e.style.color = 'blue';
        }
    }
</script>

<ul>
    <li><p id="skg" onclick="toggleColor(this);">SKG</p></li>
    <li><p id="tech" onclick="toggleColor(this);">Tech</p></li>
    <li><p id="upd" onclick="toggleColor(this);">UPD</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am new to programming. It was suggested that I learn javascript before I dive into jquery

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried jQuery instead?

```
jQuery(".color").click(function(){
   if(jQuery(this).hasClass("blue"))
      jQuery(this).removeClass("blue").addClass("orange");
   else
      jQuery(this).removeClass("orange").addClass("blue");
});
```

Comment: This simple task could be handled without any libraries.

Comment: This not solved the issue, there is no element with class 'color'. In the other hand with this solution you need to create the css classes blue and orange and you don't specify that.